# Converter to Bool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, binding

I have a normal `Checkbox`, where I want to set the `IsChecked` property to a `Binding` resource.
The resource is a self written class `myClass`, which can be `null` or referenced (means not `null`).

The `Checkbox` should be **NOT** checked, if the assigned object `myObject` (out of `myClass`) is `null`
and checked, if it is not `null`.

**What do I have to write in the `IsChecked="..."` property in my `xaml` file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a style with a `DataTrigger` that sets the `IsChecked` property.

```
<CheckBox>
   <CheckBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
         <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyObject}" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

An alternative is to create a reusable value converter.

```
public class NotNullToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value != null;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter in any resource dictionary, e.g. application resources.

```
<local:NotNullToBooleanConverter x:Key="NotNullToBooleanConverter"/>
```

This converter can be used directly in the binding.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NotNullToBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: My personal preference for the ConvertBack() method in one way converters is to return Binding.DoNothing rather than throw an exception. I find the explicit instruction to the binding engine to ignore the result causes me less anxiety than a method that is guaranteed to throw unnecessarily should it ever be called. :)